# ELB health check hitting wrong endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-application-load-balancer, health-check

My .NET Core Elastic beanstalk app is healthy but when i check the logs i see the following:

```
10.3.12.142 - - [06/Feb/2022:17:54:53 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "10.3.2.20"
10.3.11.145 - - [06/Feb/2022:17:54:57 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "10.3.1.114"
10.3.11.145 - - [06/Feb/2022:17:55:07 +0000] "GET /_system/health HTTP/1.1" 200 232 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
10.3.12.142 - - [06/Feb/2022:17:55:07 +0000] "GET /_system/health HTTP/1.1" 200 232 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
10.3.11.145 - - [06/Feb/2022:17:55:07 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "10.3.1.114"
10.3.11.145 - - [06/Feb/2022:17:55:22 +0000] "GET /_system/health HTTP/1.1" 200 237 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
10.3.12.142 - - [06/Feb/2022:17:55:22 +0000] "GET /_system/health HTTP/1.1" 200 237 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
```

`/_system/health` is the real health endpoint but i don't understand why ELB is hitting `/` instead of just `/_system/health` which ofcourse result in 404 which is expected from the app.

I have the following terraform config for health check and i don't use `.ebextensions`

```
setting {
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:process:default"
    name      = "HealthCheckPath"
    value     = "/_system/health"
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application"
    name      = "Application Healthcheck URL"
    value     = "/_system/health"
  }
```

**Edit 1**

After i change the healthcheck path to `/health`(thanks @Marcin i notice that `ELB-HealthChecker` is still hitting `/`

```
10.3.11.145 - - [07/Feb/2022:08:35:08 +0000] "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 200 227 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
10.3.12.142 - - [07/Feb/2022:08:35:08 +0000] "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 200 232 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
10.3.12.142 - - [07/Feb/2022:08:35:13 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "10.3.2.20"
```

Answer (score 1):

`/_system/health` is not supported. The [valid paths](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-elasticbeanstalkapplication) are:

```
/ (HTTP GET to root path)

/health

HTTPS:443/

HTTPS:443/health
```

Comment: I missed that and i change the path to `/heath` but i see that HealthChecker is still hitting `/` .

Comment: @user2650277 The log shows that it is also hitting ` /health`. Maybe you have both of them specified?

Comment: I have /heath set as health endpoint. My infra is build with terraform and i never change the endpoint manually